# How to find the latest date and price>0 per id?

Tags: postgresql

In POSTGRESQL 13, I have a table of ids,dates, prices.

I simply want to have the latest date where the price is greater than 0 per id.
One row per id.

So the optimal output is :

```
id | the_date | price
1   2013-08-09  0.45
2   2013-08-11  0.34
```

I have an SQL fiddle at this link :
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a89bbbc922601be5465ad764fd035161

I have tried an INNER JOIN with the MAX date unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
select i.id, i.the_date, i.price 
from inventory as i, (
    select id, max(the_date) as max_date 
    from inventory 
       where price > 0
    group by id
) as c where c.id = i.id and i.the_date = c.max_date
```

[Demo in dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=823f207fa25c302755355030680d9b5b)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) 
  id, the_date, price
FROM inventory
WHERE price>0
ORDER BY id ASC, the_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.

```
SELECT inventory.id, the_date, price
FROM inventory
join (select id,max(the_date) md from inventory where price>0 group by id ) d
on inventory.id=d.id and the_date=d.md
```

If you want a row for id's with not price you'd use left join.